# Do PS Vita backups contain activation info?

Tags: ps-vita

*By saying "backups" I mean the backup files created when using the "backup" option in the Content Manager.

I bought and downloaded some PS Mobile (PSM) games, and want to keep playing them. Now that the PSM platform is discontinued, further activations wouldn't be possible after Sep. 10. The real problem, however, is that I need to format the console to change accounts. I'm afraid that the activation info would be gone if I format the console and I would never be able to play the PSM games after Sep. 10.
Do the backups contain activation info, or more precisely, the PSM activation info?

Comment: I'd recommend using a new card for your other account, rather than format your current one every time you want to change the account. And if you *do* have another memory card, you can safely see for yourself, by backing up from one card and restoring to the other. Unfortunately, I can't do it myself since I don't have a second card, and because PSM was never released in my region, hence I wouldn't have any software to test on. My guess, however, is that the backups are probably already activated, since there's a version of CMA that doesn't require an internet connection, but I don't know.

Comment: Multiple sources confirm that accounts are tied to BOTH the console AND the memory card. So just swapping memory cards won't do. For your "backups are probably already activated" claim, I see no sources confirming that. And those "CMA without Internet" things (there are two) are made by third parties. It doesn't prove that "backups are already activated".

Answer (score 0):

(edit, complete re-write)

No. Apparently not.

Back when Fallout 4 came out I did a system back and switched regions on my Vita so I could remote play from a different account. When I did the system restore my games were working. I was for sure able to boot *rymdkapsel*. I haven't tried any games since until tonight when I went to boot the game again and now it's telling me to activate my system for PSM and of course, when I click it I get an error. All I've done since last play was to take any system updates that were pushed out so I don't know what happened. But, based on what's going on now. I'm going to say no, don't risk it.

Comment: I kept my system at 3.52 to keep the mail app exploit, so what you said should apply for me. That's a great relief, knowing that there is a way to keep playing my PSM games while still being able to switch regions. I would have a try later, and if it works for me I would mark your answer as best.

Comment: Woah! Hold that thought. I just went to launch rymdkapsel and for some reason it's asking me to perform activation. This totally worked after restore before. All I've done is taken the system updates since then. I'm super pissed. I'm going to check my other games and I may have to change my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I haven't done anything so far. But one difference between us is that I'm not gonna take any system updates... Still don't wanna risk it though